# How to smoothly animate, customize color and control jQuery UI progressbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to animating, customizing jQuery UI progressbar and controlling it by simple input values for example in order to check the checkbox will result in increase of progress bar and same by unchecked, it decrease the bar (smoothly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is my code I've tried and it works, just wanted to share with everyone.

just a little change in jquery-ui.css:

```
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    margin: -1px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Progressbar - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />-->
  <script>
  var x=0.1;
  /* Just display progress bar at 1st*/
  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: x
    });
  });

  function update(){
    // For 25% increase
     var c1 = $('input[name="c1"]:checked').length > 0;
    if(c1){
     x=25;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    x+=25;
    }
     if(!c1){
     x-=24.9;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    }
    // For 50% increase
    var c2 = $('input[name="c2"]:checked').length > 0;
    if(c2){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    x+=25;
    }
     if(!c2){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x-25 });
    }
    // For 75% increase
    var c3 = $('input[name="c3"]:checked').length > 0;
    if(c3){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    x+=25;
    }
     if(!c3){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x-25 });
    }
    // For 100% increase
    var c4 = $('input[name="c4"]:checked').length > 0;
    if(c4){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    x+=25;
    }
     if(!c4){
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x-25 });
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="progressbar" style="width:400px; height:15px; box-shadow:#666 0px 2px 2px"></div>
<br />
25% <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" onChange="update();" /> 
&nbsp;
50% <input type="checkbox" name="c2" id="c2" onChange="update();" /> 
&nbsp;
75% <input type="checkbox" name="c3" id="c3" onChange="update();" />  
&nbsp;
100% <input type="checkbox" name="c4" id="c4" onChange="update();" />  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: would really appreciate If any one could help in customizing this progress bar by using some image or custom css code. Thanks